# error in event firing

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a text box in which I m trying to call a function on its OnBlur event.
 The function is defined in the aspx.cs page.
 Problem arises when I try to debug, it says the function Text_Blur is not defined.
 Below is the code:
 Front end:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtAutoComplete" runat="server" OnBlur="Text_Blur" CssClass="TextStyleFilter"></asp:TextBox>
```

Code Behind, aspx.cs:

```
public event EventHandler OnChange;

 protected void Text_Blur(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (OnChange != null)
            OnChange(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

I googled and understood that OnBlur calls for a Javascript function, but I need to set up an event handler for another user control on OnBlur or even OnChange..
Is it possible to do so via Javascript?
Plz suggest..any pointers will be highly appreciated.

-Anurag

Comment: Can you give more details about the other user control? What is it and how is it rendered?

Comment: what is your final requirement on "onBlur",what should happen on blur ?

Comment: @JurgenStillaert:Here's my case.I hv a usercontrol A having a textbox and a button.The textbox is being targeted by an AJAX autocomplete extender.I need to use this usercntrol A twice in another usercontrol B.On debugging I cud find that the condition in AJAXservice.svc.cs aint correct and hence to debug further, am trying to have an event fired on OnBlur or OnChange which will invoke an eventhandler for usercntrol B, where I wud assign some common session var's and check the appropriate conditions in AJAXservice.svc.cs.Hope u get what I am tryin to say... :)

Comment: @sajanyamaha:Either on OnBlur or OnChange of the textbox, I need to have an eventhandler called which will see the existence of the usercontrol B and I will call another Javascript function on the call of eventhandler in usercntrol B

Comment: @user1638283 I almost get what you want, but some code would clarify things (not only for me I guess). Furthermore, you have to ask yourself if you are using the right tools for doing this. Using user controls and Ajax toolkit is great but will complicate things (as you are expericing now) and will increase the work load on the server. I suggest to shift more to a JQuery Ajax approach, where you can easily bind events to DOM controls.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert:I get what you are tryin to convey..But I dnt knw JQuery and I dnt think my client will allow dat....n how to post code in the comment section??

Comment: @user1638283 Try to edit you post.

Comment: @JurgenStillaert: I am not able to edit my post..the code which I enter over there dsnt reflect...Apologies to take ur precious time...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, OnBlur expects a client side handler, not a server side function. So define a javascript function:

```
<script type="text">
    function Text_Blur() {
        // this function will be executed when the textbox looses focus
    }
</script>
```

If you want to trigger some server side method from within the javascript function you could use AJAX.

Comment: Hi Darin..thanks for your keen reply...For debugging my AJAX autocomplete autoextender within a generic user control I am trying to invoke an eventhandler on either OnBlur or OnClick..I surely don't wana use another AJAX control..:P..Do you have any other suggestions?TIA